# How to send Hash to USB token for encryption while signing pdf

Tags: itext, digital-signature, hsm

I am Implementing Digital Signature in PDF using usb token. Now According to the digital Signature implementation through usbToken contains following steps.

1. Hash of a PDF is generated and pass to the USB token.
2. That hash will be encrypted by private key inside USB token.
3. And that encrypted hash will be appended in certificate that we will get in our application.

I have implemented signature Utility using java, but i want to know how we can pass hash of document to USB Token for encryption of that hash.

Comment: Usb tokens are connected usually trough a PKCS#11 bridge or installing a driver for Windows keystore. Read the development manual

Comment: Yeah , I have implemented it through PKCS#11, but now i want to send hash so that HSM can encrypt them and then that encrypted hash would be append in the certificate so it will check the authenticity of the file.

Comment: I guess you can use Sun PKCS11 Provider with the driver provided by the manufacturer and use some of the supported digital signature algorithms as `Sha256WithRSA` in the usual way. What have you tried?

Comment: I have resolved it. Thanks